# Reports in Jasper have no results when export in XLSX

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a JRXML with an SQL query inside the template. If I try to generate report (from java and Tibco Jasper Report) the preview and the pdf show me the correct data. The Excel version instead show me only the tables, without any rows (that I see in the preview). Alle the tables are designed with jr:table.

Anyone know why this happens?

Thanks

Luigi

Comment: Why downvote? It's a common mistakes and this can be helpful to detect why this behaviour happens. Nah!

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

The issue was a tiny text field (most probably a type during cut and paste inside the jasper report tool) overlapped on the jr:table.

Removed this, the report is correctly rendered also on xlsx.